# Solr query response in json

Tags: json, solr, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am implementing solr facet query. I need to get the response as json. I read that I can't do this using solrj and there is another way to do this by query a HTTPSolrServer.

Here is my code:

```
 SolrServer solr = SolrServerHelper.GetServer();

 SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
 query.setQuery("*:*");
 query.setFacet(true);
 query.addFacetField("status");
 query.addFacetField("type");
 query.add("wt","json");

 QueryResponse res = solr.query(query);
 List<FacetField> results=  res.getFacetFields();
```

I need help execute the query by HTTPSolrServer to get the results as json?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011637/using-solrj-to-retrieve-a-solrdocument-in-json-format