# Inserting a POJO tree using SOLRJ

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, solr, solrj

I am currently following these instructions to add data to SOLR:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Directly_adding_POJOs_to_Solr

However, I have a bean attribute that is another class. Something like bellow. Is it possible to index that the same way? I am not sure on how to config solr for that.

```
public class User {
    @Field
    String id;

    @Field("cat")
    List<Category> categories;
}

public class Category {
    @Field
    String id;

    @Field
    String name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, complex types are not supported with SolrJ only simple types. Please see this previous question - [solrj: how to store and retrieve List via multivalued field in index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633684/solrj-how-to-store-and-retrieve-listpojo-via-multivalued-field-in-index) as well as the open issue [SOLR-1945](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1945)