# Using POJO with nested classes with JAXB and Solr annotations

Tags: java, solr, jaxb, annotations

I would like to have as few classes as possible, so I would like to construct **a JAXB and Solr annotated POJO**, as you might guess, to consume XML, marshall it to a Company object and index it.

I have no problem with marshalling - the Company object gets constructed just fine. The problem I am having is how to annotate the Company POJO to create a **multivalue string solr field**.

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<company>
    <registryNumber>5226805000</registryNumber>
    <names>
        <name>name1</name>
        <name>name2</name>
    </names>
</company>
```

and my current pathetic attempt for the Company POJO looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "company")
public class Company {

    public Company() {}

    @XmlElement
    @Field("id")
    public String registryNumber; 

    public static class Names {
        public Names() {}

        @XmlElement(name = "name")
        @Field("title")
        public List<Name> name;

        public static class Name {
            public Name() {}

            @XmlValue
            public String value;
        }
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "names")
    public Names names;

}
```

The two unit test I have crafted:

```
public class CompanySearchTest extends AbstractSolrTestCase {

    private SolrServer server;

    private Company company;

    @Before
    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(h.getCoreContainer(), h.getCore().getName());

        company = new Company();
        company.registryNumber = "5226805000";
        Company.Names.Name name1 = new Company.Names.Name();
        name1.value = "name1";
        Company.Names.Name name2 = new Company.Names.Name();
        name1.value = "name2";
        Company.Names names = new Company.Names();
        names.name = Arrays.asList(name1, name2);

        server.addBean(company);
        server.commit();
    }

    @After
    public void destroy() {
        h.getCoreContainer().shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void searchByIdTest() throws IOException, SolrServerException {
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery("id:5226805000");

        QueryResponse response = server.query(query);

        List<Company> companiesFound = response.getBeans(Company.class);

        assertEquals(1L, companiesFound.size());
        assertEquals("5226805000", companiesFound.get(0).registryNumber);    
    }

    @Test
    public void searchByMultivalueNameTest() throws IOException, SolrServerException {
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery("title:name1");

        QueryResponse response = server.query(query);

        List<Company> companiesFound = response.getBeans(Company.class);

        assertEquals(1L, companiesFound.size());
        assertEquals("name1", companiesFound.get(0).names.name.get(0).value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getSchemaFile() {
        return "solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml";
    }

    @Override
    public String getSolrConfigFile() {
        return "solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml";
    }
}
```

The test searchByIdTest() passes, while the searchByMultivalueNameTest() miserably fails as no company is found by searching with:

```
query.setQuery("title:name1");
```

The solr schema I am using is the provided with solr 4.0.0 (collection 1 example).

Can someone give me some hints on **how**, if at all possible, **should I annotate the Company POJO** or what modifications should I make.

The goal is to have `<name>name1</name>` and `<name>name2</name>` indexed as multivalue solr string field as defined in example solr schema with the:

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

so the company can be found by searching "title:name1" or by "title:name2".

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that SolrJ does not support complex types for Multi-Valued fields. See this previous question - [solrj: how to store and retrieve List via multivalued field in index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633684/solrj-how-to-store-and-retrieve-listpojo-via-multivalued-field-in-index)

You will need to change your field definition to the following:

```
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    @Field("title")
    public List<String> name;
```

Comment: Thanks Paige. Had a hunch on this one.

Answer (score 1):

As Paige pointed out:

> SolrJ does not support complex types for Multi-Valued fields

I have modified the Company POJO (I love to delete lines of my own code!):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "company")
public class Company {
    public Company() {}

    @XmlElement
    @Field("id")
    public String registryNumber;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "names")
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    @Field("title")
    public List<String> names;
}
```

The XML stays the same of course.

The unit test setUp() method is also simplified:

```
@Before
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(h.getCoreContainer(), h.getCore().getName());

    company = new Company();
    company.registryNumber = "5226805000";
    company.names= Arrays.asList("name1", "name2");

    server.addBean(company);
    server.commit();
}
```

The assertions are simplified also, but I added two more queries to confirm correct search is happening:

```
@Test
    public void searchByMultivalueNameTest() throws IOException, SolrServerException {
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery("title:name1");

        QueryResponse response = server.query(query);

        List<Company> companiesFound = response.getBeans(Company.class);

        assertEquals(1L, companiesFound.size());
        assertEquals("name1", companiesFound.get(0).names.get(0));

        // 2nd query
        query.clear();
        query.setQuery("title:name2");

        response = server.query(query);

        companiesFound = response.getBeans(Company.class);

        assertEquals(1L, companiesFound.size());
        assertEquals("name2", companiesFound.get(0).names.get(1));

        // 3rd query
        query.clear();
        query.setQuery("title:name1 AND title:name2");

        response = server.query(query);

        companiesFound = response.getBeans(Company.class);

        assertEquals(1L, companiesFound.size());
        assertEquals("name1", companiesFound.get(0).names.get(0));
        assertEquals("name2", companiesFound.get(0).names.get(1));      

    }
```

That's it. I hope someone else find this useful.